# Unity3D рисование кривых

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Как в `Unity3D`, для `2D` игры рисовать произвольные линии с помощью касаний (правда мне кажется, что с мышой все так же).

Например, я нажал на экран, нарисовал произвольный круг, после чего палец убрал и этот объект создался, и уже по возможности добавился компонент `Rigidbody2D`, и верная маска коллизий, что бы не квадрат был, который по краях ограничивает область, а крива. И на сколько я знаю, `Rigidbody` и `MeshCollider` вместе не работают(но это в `3D`).

Comment: Можно использовать `Line Renderer` для рисования линий http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html  .......зачем вам коллиззи и Rigidbody? что хотите добиться  в итоге?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а можно ли на эту линию адекватно повесить `rigidbody` и коллайдер?

Comment: Сомневаюсь.... линия это множество точек. Коллайдер если вешать, то не на конкретную линию, а на маленькие промежутки между точками, каждые (к примеру) две штуки...... Вообще зависит от задачи.. Если наносить `damage` то не обязательно даже коллайдеры вешать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Линию от точки к точке рисуем при помощи двух треугольников, создаем MeshRenderer и для него создаем последовательно от точки к точке линии, дополняя. Код из нашего проекта , брал пример из сети, рисовал 2D графики.
Для физики можно повешать потом на объект Rigidbody2D и попробовать либо PolygonCollider2D, либо придется на каждую линию BoxCollider2D вешать.

Вот код класса рисующего линии по точкам добавляемым в процессе рисования

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using ThreadPriority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority;

[RequireComponent (typeof (MeshFilter))]

/// <summary>
/// Generates a trail that is always facing upwards using the scriptable mesh interface.
/// vertex colors and uv's are generated similar to the builtin Trail Renderer.
/// To use it
/// 1. create an empty game object
/// 2. attach this script and a MeshRenderer
/// 3. Then assign a particle material to the mesh renderer
/// </summary>
public class Line : MonoBehaviour {

public float height = 2.0f;
public float time = 2.0f;
public bool localDraw = false;
public float minDistance = 0.1f;

public Color startColor = Color.white;
public Color endColor = new Color (1, 1, 1, 0);
[HideInInspector]
public Mesh mesh;

protected List<TrailSection> sections;
protected TrailSection lastSection; 

private float testNormal = 1.0f;
private Transform cachedTransform;
private Vector3[] vertices;
private Color[] colors;
private Vector2[] uv;
private Vector3[] normals;
private int[] triangles;
private bool needUpdate = false;
private Thread threadCalcMesh;

private object lockOn = new object();


// Use this for initialization
protected virtual void Awake () {
    // Rebuild the mesh
    cachedTransform = transform;
    mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    Clear();
    /*AddPoint(new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f));
    AddPoint(new Vector3(5.0f,4.0f));
    AddPoint(new Vector3(8.0f,2.0f));
    AddPoint(new Vector3(10.0f,12.0f));
        ReDraw();*/
}

virtual public void Clear() {
    mesh.Clear();
    sections = new List<TrailSection>();
    lastSection = null;
    transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    /*if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
    //  this.AddPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        testNormal *= -1;
        Sender.SendEventHierarchy(EventDiagram.UPDATE, this);
    }*/
    if (needUpdate)
    {
        //if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockOn))
        lock (lockOn)
        {
            mesh.Clear();
            mesh.vertices = vertices;
            mesh.colors = colors;
            mesh.uv = uv;
            mesh.triangles = triangles;
            mesh.normals = normals;
            needUpdate = false;
        }
    }
}

virtual public void ReDraw(){
    MeshUpdate();
}
virtual protected void OnEnable(){
    Sender.SendEventHierarchy(EventDiagram.UPDATE, this);
}

virtual protected void OnDisable(){
}

virtual public void AddPoint(Vector3    position){

    Vector3 vDistance = Vector3.zero;
    if (lastSection != null){
        vDistance = lastSection.point - position;
        vDistance.Scale(transform.localScale);
    }
    // Add a new trail section
    if (lastSection == null || vDistance.sqrMagnitude > minDistance * minDistance)
    {
        var section = new TrailSection();
        section.point = position;
        if (localDraw)
            section.forwardDir = Vector3.forward;
        else
            section.forwardDir = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        sections.Add(section); 
        lastSection = section;
    }
    updateAfterAddPoint();
}

virtual protected void updateAfterAddPoint(){
}

public void MeshUpdate () {

// We need at least 2 sections to create the line
    if (sections.Count < 2)
        return;

    if (threadCalcMesh != null && threadCalcMesh.IsAlive)
        return;

    threadCalcMesh = new Thread(recalcMesh);
    threadCalcMesh.IsBackground = true;
    threadCalcMesh.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;

    threadCalcMesh.Start(getVectorScale());
    //thread.Join();

}

void recalcMesh(object scaleV)
{
    int sectCount = sections.Count;

    int vert = (sectCount - 1) * 4;
    Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[vert];
    Color[] colors = new Color[vert];
    Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[vert];
    Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[vert];

    TrailSection previousSection;// = sections[0];
    TrailSection currentSection = sections[0];
    TrailSection nextSection;// = sections[0];

    // Use matrix instead of transform.TransformPoint for performance reasons
    //Matrix4x4 localSpaceTransform = transform.worldToLocalMatrix;
    Vector3 upDir, upDirCross;
    Vector3 vec;
    Vector3 vec1, vec2, vecCross;
    int idx;

    Vector3 vectorScale = (Vector3) scaleV;

    // Generate vertex, uv and colors
    for (int i = 1; i < sectCount; i++)
    {
        previousSection = currentSection;
        currentSection = sections[i];
        if (i < sectCount - 1)
            nextSection = sections[i + 1];
        else
            nextSection = currentSection;
        // Calculate u for texture uv and color interpolation
        vec = currentSection.point - previousSection.point;

        vec1 = currentSection.point - previousSection.point;
        vec2 = currentSection.point - nextSection.point;

        vecCross = Vector3.Cross(vec1, vec2);

        // Calculate upwards direction
        upDir = Vector3.Cross(-vec, Vector3.forward);
        upDir.Normalize();
        upDir *= height / 2;
        upDir = Vector3.Scale(upDir, vectorScale);

        idx = (i - 1) * 4;

        if (i == 1)
        {
            vertices[idx + 0] = previousSection.point - upDir;
            vertices[idx + 1] = previousSection.point + upDir;
        }
        else
        {
            vertices[idx + 0] = previousSection.crossUp ? previousSection.point - upDir : vertices[idx - 2];
            vertices[idx + 1] = !previousSection.crossUp ? previousSection.point + upDir : vertices[idx - 1]; ;
        }

        if (i + 1 == sectCount)
        {
            vertices[idx + 2] = currentSection.point - upDir;
            vertices[idx + 3] = currentSection.point + upDir;
        }
        else
        {
            // ищем точку пересечения секции со следующей секцией
            currentSection.crossUp = Vector3.Dot(vecCross, currentSection.forwardDir) < 0;

            upDirCross = Vector3.Cross(vec2.normalized - vec1.normalized, currentSection.forwardDir);
            //upDirCross = vec1 + vec2;
            upDirCross.Normalize();
            //float sinb = Vector3.Cross(vec1.normalized, vec2.normalized).magnitude; 
            upDirCross *= height / 2;// / sinb;
            upDirCross = Vector3.Scale(upDirCross, vectorScale);

            // Поиск точки как сумму векторов
            /*vec1.Normalize();
            vec1 *= height / 2;
            vec1 = Vector3.Scale(vec1, vectorScale);
            vec2.Normalize();
            vec2 *= height / 2;
            vec2 = Vector3.Scale(vec2, vectorScale);
            upDirCross = -vec1 - vec2;*/

            if (currentSection.crossUp)
            {
                vertices[idx + 2] = currentSection.point - upDir;
                vertices[idx + 3] = currentSection.point + upDirCross;
            }
            else
            {
                vertices[idx + 2] = currentSection.point - upDirCross;
                vertices[idx + 3] = currentSection.point + upDir;
            }
        }

        float u = 0.0f;

        u = Mathf.Clamp01((float)(i - 1) / sectCount);
        uv[idx + 0] = new Vector2(u, 0);
        uv[idx + 1] = new Vector2(u, 1);
        u = Mathf.Clamp01((float)i / sectCount);
        uv[idx + 2] = new Vector2(u, 0);
        uv[idx + 3] = new Vector2(u, 1);

        // fade colors out over time
        Color interpolatedColor = Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, u);
        colors[idx + 0] = interpolatedColor;
        colors[idx + 1] = interpolatedColor;
        colors[idx + 2] = interpolatedColor;
        colors[idx + 3] = interpolatedColor;

        normals[idx + 0] = currentSection.forwardDir * testNormal;
        normals[idx + 1] = currentSection.forwardDir * testNormal;
        normals[idx + 2] = currentSection.forwardDir * testNormal;
        normals[idx + 3] = currentSection.forwardDir * testNormal;
    }

    // Generate triangles indices

    int[] triangles = new int[(sectCount - 1) * 6 + (sectCount - 2) * 3];
    int sectionNum = 1;
    int idx4, idx9;
    float cntStep = ((float)triangles.Length) / 9;
    for (int i = 0; i < cntStep; i++)
    {
        idx9 = i * 9;
        idx4 = i * 4;
        //Первый треугольник
        triangles[idx9 + 0] = idx4;
        triangles[idx9 + 1] = idx4 + 1;
        triangles[idx9 + 2] = idx4 + 2;
        //Второй треугольник
        triangles[idx9 + 3] = idx4 + 2;
        triangles[idx9 + 4] = idx4 + 1;
        triangles[idx9 + 5] = idx4 + 3;

        if (sectionNum + 1 == sectCount)
            break;
        //соединяющий треугольник
        if (sections[sectionNum].crossUp)
        {

            triangles[idx9 + 6] = idx4 + 2;
            triangles[idx9 + 7] = idx4 + 3;
            triangles[idx9 + 8] = idx4 + 4;

        }
        else
        {
            //соединяющий треугольник
            triangles[idx9 + 6] = idx4 + 2;
            triangles[idx9 + 7] = idx4 + 3;
            triangles[idx9 + 8] = idx4 + 5;

        }
        sectionNum++;

    }
    lock (lockOn)
    {
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.colors = colors;
        this.uv = uv;
        this.triangles = triangles;
        this.normals = normals;
        needUpdate = true;
    }
}

protected Vector3 getVectorScale(){
    return new Vector3(1 / transform.localScale.x, 1/ transform.localScale.y, 1 / transform.localScale.z);
}

}
```

Предупреждаю код из проекта, поэтому могут быть какие то хвосты, вроде вызова внешних событий и т.п. Как использовать вроде бы есть в комментариях

Comment: подожду код, пожалуй) и спасибо за направление, в которое нужно искать)

Comment: @ЯрославМовчан добавил код